# Power supply in custom computer

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I am building a new computer and would like to double check on the power supply. I am using [Building a PC, Part VI: Rebuilding](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/building-a-pc-part-vi-rebuilding.html) as a guideline, updating parts to newer ones available, but am staying within the lines so to speak (aside from the GPUs).

Overall this will be a gaming rig with 2 x 6870s in crossfire, 4x2 DDR3 DIMMS, i7, etc.  (I am still looking into water cooling units and don't know how that will impact psu requirements.)

I have churned the expected setup though the psu calcs on newegg, outervision, and used ibuypower as a reference point.  These break down as:

- outervision - 501W
- newegg - 780W
- ibuypower - 850W

I understand these are approximations/best guesses.  Based on the Jeff's article above and the reviews on newegg I believe I am going to go with the CORSAIR HX Series (approximate current prices):

- 650W - $120
- 750W - $140
- 850W - $170
- 1000W - $230

It's probably silly to even be concerned about going up to the 850W at this point based on what I want to do with the box.  Should I even be looking at the 1000W or is that just totally unnecessary?  (not that that's a bad thing)

I am really enjoying this process and appreciate input, thanks.

Comment: With `with 2 x 6870s in crossfire, 4x2 DDR3 DIMMS, i7` it's not silly to seriously look at the 850W powerplant.

Comment: Also wanted to mention I am not looking at any OC at this time.

Comment: @Sathya Agreed, it's really down to the 850 vs 1000.

Comment: If you can stretch it, it's worth getting the 1000W. A good PSU lays a solid foundation & it's not like the 1000W will consume 1000W - the actual power consumption will be as required.

Comment: With Sathya on this - if you can afford it, kick in for the 1000W.

Comment: a bit off-topic on the question... but 3x4GB or 3x2GB of a good DDR3 memory would be more suitable to a i7, right? I got 3x2GB on a i7 950. on-topic: go for a 1000W PSU, don't think it is worth saving 60 bucks on this kind of configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments,

With 2 x 6870s in crossfire, 4x2 DDR3 DIMMS, i7 and a possible water cooling you should be looking at a 850W PSU. And if you can stretch it - a 1000W would be ideal.  A good PSU can help your system and can cope up with any possible future upgrades.